# Por que o código retorna error dumped core?

Tags: c, float, referência, booleano, buffer-overflow

Me deparei com o seguintes erros: floating point exception e dumped core para o mesmo código.
Não entendi muito bem a razão de ocorrer esse erro. Coloquei o código em um debugger e pelo o que vi o scanf não está lendo nenhum número. Como posso arrumar isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int n, i = 0, j = 0;
bool x;

bool is_prime(int num)
{
    while(i <= 20)
    {
      if(num % i == 0)
        j++;
      i++;
    }
    if(j > 2)
    {
      return false;  
    }
    else
      return true;
}

int main()
{
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d", is_prime(n));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como `i` começa em zero, vc acaba fazendo uma divisão por zero em `num % i` (pois o operador `%` é o resto da divisão, e como não dá pra dividir por zero, dá erro). Faça o `i` começar em 1 (e faça isso dentro da função, em vez de criar `i` fora dela, senão você só conseguirá usar a função uma vez). Além disso, por que a condição de parada é `i <= 20`? Se digitar um número maior que 20, não vai contar todos os divisores corretamente, deveria ser `i <= num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n, i = 0, j = 0;
bool x;

bool is_prime(int num)
{
    while(i <= 20)
    {
      if(num % i == 0)
        j++;
      i++;
    }
    if(j > 2)
    {
      return false;  
    }
    else
      return true;
}
```

Não escreva assim. Essas variáveis com esses nomes singelos, `i, j n` declaradas fora de qualquer função passam a ser globais e valer por todo o código. Isso quer dizer que qualquer parte do seu programa que usar um `i` estará usando O MESMO `i`. Sabe quanto tempo demora para isso cair em sua cabeça ao você usar por engano um `j` em dois lugares? minutos. E quanto demora pra achar o erro e arrumar? E se o programa não tiver só 20 linhas? ...

Nunca use nada global. E afinal é proibido em toda parte mesmo.

```
int main()
{
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d", is_prime(n));
  return 0;
}
```

Não escreva assim também. Tem um manual? Um livro? Leu a documentação antes de usar scanf()? Usa um IDE que mostra os protótipos das funções?

- `scanf()` retorna um `int` com o total de valores que conseguiu ler. No seu caso tentou ler um só usando o tal `%d`. Então `scanf()` vai retornar 1 se leu, ou 0 se não leu ou -1 se deu algum erro. Só que você não testou **NADA** e seguiu cegamente. Qual o propósito de saber que um número que você não sabe se leu é ou não primo?
- e essa linha

```
  printf("%d", is_prime(n));
```

acaba sendo um desastre: era sua esperança de saber se leu algo e o que está indo para a função `is_prime()`. Mas como você juntou o `printf()` e a chamada a `is_prime()` no mesmo comando até o uso do debugger ficou prejudicado porque não pode parar no meio da linha. Enquanto está aprendendo ou ao menos enquanto está testando nunca faça isso. escreva separado

```
    printf("%d foi o valor lido\n", n );
    printf("%d foi o retorno de is_prime (0 = nao primo)\n", is_prime(n));
```

E saberá se o programa cancelou porque leu algum lixo ou se `is_prime()` cancelou, e com qual valor de `n`. E claro declare `n` aí dentro. Algo assim seria mais seguro:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    if ( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
    {
        printf("Não leu nada. Encerrando\n");
        return -1;
    };
    printf("%d foi o valor lido\n", n );
    printf("%d foi o retorno de is_prime (0 = nao primo)\n", is_prime(n));
    return 0;
};
```

#### E `is_prime()`

Que significa o 20 lá? Qual a lógica do que está escrevendo? O simples para identificar um primo `N` desse modo é

- ir dividindo `N` por valores `i` como fez, valores menores que `N` e se `N` for múltiplo de `i` retornar false.
- até onde ir com i? até 20? até `N-1`? Não, claro. Se `N` é múltiplo de `i` então claro de tem um `j` tal que `i * j == N`
- conforme aumenta `i` `j` diminui, certo? Por exemplo 12 é múltiplo de 2, 3, 4 e 6. Então para o maior i tem o menor j: 6x2 = 12. Para o menor i tem o maior `j` claro: 2x6 = 12. E eles podem ser iguais: `5 * 5 == 25` e só aí descobre que 25 não é primo. Então o maior valor que precisa testar é o da raiz quadrada de `N`...
- para não ter que usar raiz quadrada --- `sqrt()` em C --- e ter que incluir math.h e chamar uma função que pode levar uma eternidade em relação a uma simples multiplicação, pode até usar outra condição: procurar múltiplos `i` até que `i*i` ser maior que `N`, trocando o quadrado pela raiz quadrada.
- pode usar nomes mais expressivos, e declarar as variáveis onde elas vão ser usadas porque é mais seguro assim. Algo assim deve funcionar:

```
bool is_prime(int N)
{
    int divisor = 2;
    if ( N == 2 ) return true;
    while( divisor * divisor <= N )
    {
      if ( N % divisor == 0) return false;
      divisor += 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

E talvez concorde que é mais fácil de ler.

Mas como é um loop e começa por dois e termina com uma condição objetiva, então um `for` pode ser mais seguro e dá pra usar usar assim:

```
bool is_prime(int N)
{
    if ( N == 2 ) return true;
    for( int divisor = 2; divisor * divisor <= N; divisor +=1  )
      if ( N % divisor == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

E ver

```
[Identificando primos]. Valor: 3
3 foi o valor lido
1 foi o retorno de is_prime (0 = nao primo)
```

#### sobre main() e um exemplo completo com as 2 funções

Esse é um programa que só faz uma coisa e só faz uma vez. É muito chato rodar o programa e ficar esperando ele perguntar o número e aí digtar o número e ele mostrar o número e dar a resposta. Em geral quando o cara roda o programa já tem um número em mente ;)
É muito mais confortável usar a linha de comando apenas, e escrever algo assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char is_prime(int);
char is_prime_while(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 0;
    if ( argc < 2)
    {
        printf("[Identificando primos]. Valor: ");
        if ( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
        {
            printf("\nNão leu nada. Encerrando\n");
            return -1;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    };
    printf("%d foi o valor lido\n", n );
    if ( is_prime(n))
        printf("%d e' primo!\n", n);
    else
        printf("%d nao e' primo!\n", n);
    return 0;
};

char is_prime(int N)
{
    if ( N == 2 ) return 1;
    for( int divisor = 2; divisor * divisor < N; divisor +=1  )
      if ( N % divisor == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

char is_prime_while(int N)
{
    int divisor = 2;
    if ( N == 2 ) return 1;
    while( divisor * divisor < N )
    {
      if ( N % divisor == 0) return 0;
      divisor += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
// fim do texto
```

E ai pode usar dos dois modos:

```
so$ gcc -o primo -Wall -O3 y.c
so$ ./primo
[Identificando primos]. Valor: 25
25 foi o valor lido
25 nao e' primo!
so$ ./primo
[Identificando primos]. Valor: 11
11 foi o valor lido
11 e' primo!
so$ ./primo 121
121 foi o valor lido
121 nao e' primo!
so$ ./primo 
[Identificando primos]. Valor: w

Não leu nada. Encerrando
so$
```

Ou seja,

- se o cara digita 'primo 22' o programa usa 22
- se o cara digita só o nome do programa, 'primo'  o program lê (e antes avisa o que vai ler)
- se o cara vai digitar e bate a mão numa letra p[or engano o programa faz o simples e diz que não leu nada.

#### sobre bool

Em C zero é falso. O resto é verdadeiro. E assim usar `stdbool` só para poder constantes `true` e `false` e declarar coisinhas como `bool` que vão ocupar afinal ao menos um byte mesmo é um pouco demais pro meu exemplo :)

#### um progama um pouco menor

Uma vez que esteja um pouco mais seguro com a leitura e o resultado pode usar algo mais compacto, usando um único `printf()` e deixado as mensagens prontas para poder abrir mão do teste. `is_prime()` retorna `0` para falso e `1` para verdadeiro então

```
    const char* msg[] = { " nao e' primo", " e' primo" };
    printf("%d %s\n", n, msg[ (int)is_prime(n)] );
```

é ligeiramente mais esperto. O programa podia ser então só

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char is_prime(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 0;
    if ( argc < 2)
    {
        printf("[Identificando primos]. Valor: ");
        if ( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
        {
            printf("\nNão leu nada. Encerrando\n");
            return -1;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    };
    const char* msg[] = { " nao e' primo", " e' primo" };
    printf("%d %s\n", n, msg[ (int)is_prime(n)] );
};

char is_prime(int N)
{
    if ( N == 2 ) return 1;
    for( int divisor = 2; divisor * divisor <= N; divisor +=1  )
      if ( N % divisor == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
// fim do texto
```